# VB.net Replace or Disable a keystroke (works even in an external program)

Tags: vb.net

This is an extension of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596674/vb-net-cannot-capture-f12-register-hotkey

which I conclude doing it this way may solve the problem easier. I have now worked on some keylogger-like program such as windowshook, but I would like to disable some keys, for example since F1 is help and F12 is console on chrome, and so on.

I would like to disable function of those keys, and make then my own hotkey for some personal use.

Answer (score 0):

i found this snippet online hope it helps

> If e.KeyCode = Keys.K Then  e.Handled = False
>
> 'Here you can send an "a" or whatever. You could use SendKeys("a"),
>   but there are cleaner ways of doing it...
>
> End If

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Correct me if I'm wrong... that don't work on External program... right?
Tried it before, don't know if they are ways of it to do it on external program... or maybe there are no ways of it...

Comment: `Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Int32) As UShort`



Create a new timer on your form, change its enabled state to true
change its interval to 50
double click the timer
add this code


`If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F1) <> 0 Then

    MessageBox.Show("You pushed F1")

End If` try this

Comment: but i dont think it does what you want with this , since it only checks after you press the key but you could close watever opened with the hotkey

Comment: I tried it before with something like this,
but have no idea where to insert the e.keycode to make it functional on external application...

https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/10258885_855486337800325_4805627276815378823_n.jpg

Comment: the timer is the only thing i can think of sorry mate